# How to distribute a person's property who doesn't have any children?

Tags: sunni, inheritance

How is the property of a deceased person who left a wife but no children distributed?

- He has 2 brothers, 1 older (no children and a widow) who died 10 years ago and another younger brother (who has 2 sons and a daughter and a widow) who died 3 month before that.
- He has 2 sisters, who both already died (both sisters have several sons and daughters).
- Some of his cousins are alive and have several sons and daughters.
- His parents are already dead.
- His younger brother has 2 sons and a daughter, who are apparently legal heirs.

Please guide me according to Qur'an and sunnah, in this case who will have a share in the property. Property is in the form of agricultural land.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the deceased person plus all of the people you have mention are Muslim and are of one religion?

Comment: Yes all are muslim (sunni)

Answer (score 3):

This [website](http://inheritance.ilmsummit.org/projects/inheritance/home.aspx) or [this](http://www.islamchannel.tv/pages/InheritCalculator.aspx) can help you.

According to both sites I mentioned, after the share of wife, *ALL*remaining assets will go to the two nephews (none will go to nieces):

```
Relative        Share Fraction    Share Percentage
--------        --------------    ----------------
Wife            1/4               25%
FullNephew 1    3/8               37.5%
FullNephew 2    3/8               37.5%
```